# Verifying ANT/Tomcat7 deployment

Tags: spring, ant, tomcat7

I'm new to Ant/Tomcat. I'm trying to setup a simple webstack with spring. The tutorial on spring.io was geared towards tomcat6 so I had to look around to sort out my build.xml. I finally found [this](http://pastebin.com/aPPXkQCd) which seems to be working but I'm (obviously) missing something because the page isn't coming up. compile/install/remove targets run fine but I don't see my app listed when I run ant list (it doesn't show up on /manager/html either).

```
list:
     [list] OK - Listed applications for virtual host localhost
     [list] /:running:0:ROOT
     [list] /manager:running:7:/usr/share/tomcat7-admin/manager
     [list] /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps:running:0:usr#share#tomcat7#webapps
     [list] /host-manager:running:1:/usr/share/tomcat7-admin/host-manager
```

Any suggestion/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here. What is it you would like a suggestion about? Also, it is not clear whether you checked that your application was successfully deployed, can you confirm if that's the case?

Comment: That's exactly my question (apologies if it wasn't obvious). Even though Ant reports no problems with build/deployment, I don't think my app is actually getting deployed. I would like to know how can I verify that? I see the war file in tomcats web app folder but localhost:8080/myappname shows 404

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<waitfor maxwait="1" maxwaitunit="minute" checkevery="1000">
  <http url="http://localhost:8080/myappname"/>
</waitfor>
```

This will wait until a valild response (response code < 400) is received from the web server for the specified URL. You might want to adjust the timing to suit to your needs.